# What is Ayurved's relation with Vedas?

Tags: vedas, ayurveda, sanskrit

I know, every text book is directly or indirectly related to vedas. This 'Ayurveda', has a 'Ved' in it.

By meaning it seems its another type of veda, but being four veda pillared, I didn't found any reference of it being of any four.

As going in between discussion, I'm sure its not any one of four vedas, yet it has a 'ved' ending with it.

I just wanted to know its relation to Vedas(Direct One, as I posted every text has at least indirect relation to veda) or if not why it got the name 'Ayurveda'.

I don't want to be offensive in nomenclature of the book, yet what I know the way Sanskrit words are created is scientific, and 'Ayur' meaning life and 'Veda' meaning 'science'(Sorry I don't have any relative english word for it.)

Comment: Veda is not just a word reffering to sepcific set of books in sanskrit it has a different meaning which is to 'know' ayur+veda means `to know` or the `knowledge of ayu or age (human body)` to know physical aspects of human body. see this http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vedas#Etymology_and_usage for meaning of word vedas.

Comment: You can ask Ayurveda related questions here: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/102499/ayurveda

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is another type of veda but it believed to be a part of Atharva-veda, as 'Veda' means 'knowledge' and 'Ayur' means 'life' in Sanskrit. Ayurveda is the most ancient science of healing which enhances longevity. It has influenced many of the older traditional methods of healing including Tibetan, Chinese and Greek medicine. Hence, Ayurveda is considered by many as the 'mother of healing.
The hymns and mantras contained in Atharva-veda were contributions of Rishis and munis or sages, over a period of time.

The Aryan who were called *'Aryavartas'* were the people who used to live in northern parts of India and Himalayas, and and is believed to be the place where the Rishis and Munis lived. At present it covers areas in countries like Nepal, India, Pakistan, Bhutan and Tibet. The civilizations of these countries are deeply influenced by the unique intellectual contributions of these Rishis and Munis. In Atharva-veda, Ayurveda is divided into 8 parts called '[Ashtaangas Ayurveda](http://www.hindupedia.com/en/Ayurveda#Ashtaangas_of_Ayurveda_-_The_Eight_Limbs_of_Ayurveda)', I am not explaining the specifics of each though.

And as you have said that you know every text books of the veda, you should have known about this.

You can read these link to get more informations

- [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atharvaveda#Divisions_and_issues_of_note)
- [Ayurveda1](http://www.allayurveda.com/discover.asp)
- [Ayurveda2](http://www.swadeshi.co/Ayurveda-history.aspx)
- [Ayurveda3](http://www.ayurvedatips.info/origin.shtml)